# Having problems loading Jquery in functions.php

Tags: functions, jquery

I'm trying to add some Jquery scripts to my Wordpress site, and unfortunately I cannot link you to the site as I'm working locally. It seems that the Jquery file is being loaded, as well as the fancyboxStyle I created, but all of the other js scripts aren't loading.

**functions.php**

```
function my_init() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    // load JS files from my theme

    wp_enqueue_script('easing', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true, $in_footer);  

    wp_enqueue_script('mouseWheel', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true, $in_footer);

    wp_register_style( 'fancyboxStyle', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/css/fancybox.css', true);

    wp_enqueue_style( 'fancyboxStyle' );

    wp_enqueue_script('fancybox', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true, $in_footer);

    wp_enqueue_script('fancyboxControls', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/fancybox/fancyboxControls.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true, $in_footer);


    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

The files are all in the correct location, but the scripts do not load within the footer (or header for that matter).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Ashley

Comment: Hi Roman, Thanks for the code but that doesn't seem to be working either. This time I don't actually have Jquery loaded either, but the fancyboxStyle is loading fine

Comment: For the next time. Please comment to my answer and use `@Roman` so I get a notification from WPSE. I've added a comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple errors here.

1. You're including CSS and JS on the same and wrong hook
2. For JS you could use `wp_enqueue_scripts`
3. For CSS you could use `wp_print_styles`
4. `wp_register_script` / `wp_enqueue_script` only accepts 4 parameters.
5. You should only **register** your scripts and **enqueue only the last one** with its dependencies. Use the third parameter to define these.

Try out this code:

**functions.php**

```
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'wpse28490_enqueueStyles');
function wpse28490_enqueueStyles() {
    wp_register_style('fancyboxStyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/fancybox.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('fancyboxStyle');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse28490_enqueueScripts');
function wpse28490_enqueueScripts() {
    if(!is_admin()) {
        // If our site is using SSL, we should load our external scripts also in HTTPS
        $protocol = (is_ssl()) ? 'https://' : 'http://';

        // jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', $protocol . 'ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js', array(), '1.6.2', true);

        // Custom scripts
        wp_register_script('jquery-easing', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);  
        wp_register_script('jquery-mouseWheel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
        wp_register_script('jquery-fancybox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
        // fancyboxControls needs jquery, jquery-mouseWheel and jquery-fancybox, so we could pass these ids to the third parameter as an array.
        wp_register_script('fancyboxControls', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/fancybox/fancyboxControls.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-easing', 'jquery-mouseWheel', 'jquery-fancybox'), '1.0', true);

        // Everything is registred, just enqueue our last script
        wp_enqueue_script('fancyboxControls');
    }
}
```

Comment: @remi90 The above script is working on a default installation. Please check your sourcecode. It could be that another script needs jQuery before the `wp_footer` hook and therefore include jquery in the header. Try disabling your plugins and test again.

Comment: It does indeed appear to work after disabling some plugins.

Thank you Roman